# PowerShell class method description is missing

Tags: powershell, class, methods

I would like to create a class with static methods. Everything works fine unless the missing description when using "Tab-Completion". If executing `[Test]::new` directly the needed input is visible. How could I achieve the same behavior seen by `[System.Guid]::new`?

[image]

```
class Test
{
    [System.String]$Property1
    [System.Int32]$Property2
    [System.DateTime]$Property3

    Test()
    {
        $this.Property1 = 'ABCD'
        $this.Property2 = 123
        $this.Property3 = [System.DateTime]::Now
    }

    Test([System.String]$Property1, [System.Int32]$Property2, [System.DateTime]$Property3)
    {
        $this.Property1 = $Property1
        $this.Property2 = $Property2
        $this.Property3 = $Property3
    }

    static [Test]new()
    {
        return [Test]::new('ABCD', 123, [System.DateTime]::Now)
    }

    static [Test]new([System.String]$Property1, [System.Int32]$Property2, [System.DateTime]$Property3)
    {
        return [Test]::new($Property1, $Property2, $Property3)
    }
}

Clear-Host
[Test]::new
[Test]::





[System.Guid]::new
```

Comment: Classic chicken/egg problem. ISE uses reflection against resolved type names to discover the method overload signatures. This means you need to actually _define_ the type (ie. _execute_ the `class ...` statement) before ISE can discover it's member details

Comment: You mean pressing Ctrl+A/F8 inside ISE to initialize the class? I did this already otherwise `[Test]::new` would fail.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I mean :) I just did so (with your code) and I get the tool tip with the correct overload signatures popping up when I type `[Test]::new` afterwards

Comment: strange, does not work for me... Still the same as shown in the picture posted initially. However so technically should be everything okay?

Comment: Did you perhaps already define a previous version of the type before adding the constructor overload? Might be that ISE caches the results the first time it tries to resolve it

Comment: Even when I open a new ISE. And the same at an other system inside Sapiens PowerShell Studio.